# Running OLEDB VB6 Windows Progam Under Wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

I'm trying to install a VB6 Windows program that uses OLEDB to access VFP tables to run under Wine 1.0.1 on Ubuntu 9.10. Wine is configured to Windows version Windows XP. The program install ran okay, and I used winetricks to install MDAC 2.8 and JET 4.0 sp7. I also installed Microsoft's vfpoledb and vfpodbc drivers. The application starts and displays an error message, **item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal**. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are there any other details about the error at all, I don't have enough experience of Wine to know whether it has an "Event Log" which may contain errors, or the application itself may maintain it's own error log in the program directory (bit of a long shot).

Comment: @Richard, this is my first use of Wine so I don't know how to do any in depth debugging either. This is all I have except that I can use a Visual Fox Pro tool from the same company to verify the tables are correct.

Comment: Are you sure that jet 4.0 is the right library?

Comment: @horatio - Yes, The program is for Windows and I have a lot of experience setting it up. I tried to do this because we sometimes get calls from a potential customer that wants to do something like this. Since Ubuntu (and Wine) have updated this error has gone away, I have new ones, but the whole thing is impossibly slow so I quit even trying to get this working completely.

Comment: ahh, somehow I missed the ask date on this. I wonder why it was up on the top of the list...

Answer (score 0):

try `winetricks mdac28`
http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks

Comment: I have used winetricks to add both MDAC 2.8 and JET 4.0: see the question. I did that to solve an error 429.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed that. I can tell you that the error usually pops up when there is a misspelled field name in the source code. Ie: rs.fields("UesrName") instead of rs.fields("UserName"). Can you verify that it does run on windows without the error?

Comment: I guess I should have included that. This is a commercial point-of-sale program running on hundreds of Windows computers from Win2k up.

Comment: Contact the developer. They may have a diagnostic tool or give you a better idea of what the problem is.

Comment: Not an option - the program is meant to run on Windows so what I am trying is unsupported.